# Prompt user with the default project installer of visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I've a c# project, and I would like to know if the default free installer, provided with visual studio 2010 allows us to prompt some information to configure the application.

if yes, how?

if no, what can you advice me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several links you should probably explore thoroughly:

[User Interface Management in Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecaca8zb(v=vs.80).aspx)

- The **User Interface Editor** can be used to specify and set properties for predefined dialog boxes that are displayed during installation on the target computer.

[Visual Studio Setup project FAQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473)

[Setup and Deployment Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx)

These will give you a pretty good overview on how to create setup projects, which ones to use, and how to customize your User Interface, once you have a setup project.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/) from Rob Aquila's Blog recently helped me out with this exact question. It runs you through the steps required to make your deployment package prompt the user for input, and then modify your app.config with those values during installation.

One pitfall from my experience came in attempting to configure custom sections in the app.config. Turns out I couldn't use the `ConfigurationSection` implementation that was already created for the application, due to assembly binding issues that I couldn't resolve. I ended up doing that using LINQ to XML in a custom Installer class.

However, modifying the `<appSettings>` settings is fairly straightforward.